# CakePHP 2.0, Submit form redirect not rendering properly

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

Hi I've created a file upload form, it all works perfectly apart from when I press submit it does not re-direct me to the Uploads/add.ctp, but it does save the file to the directory and on to the database.In fact if I point the re-direct to uploads/browse it still does not take me to uploads/browse.

This is my controller

```
public function add() {

if(!empty($this->data)){

    $file = $this->request->data['Upload']['file'];
if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK && $this->Upload->save($this->data)){
    $this->Upload->save($this->data);
    if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],APP.'webroot/files/uploads'.DS.$this->Upload->id.'.mp4')) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('<p class="uploadflash">The upload has been saved</p>', true));
    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Uploads','action' => 'add'));
    } else{

    $this->Session->setFlash(__('<p class="uploadflash">The upload could not be saved. Please, try again.</p>', true));

    }
} 


}
}
```

and this is my form

```
      <div class="maincontent">
      <?php echo $this->Form->create('Upload', array('type' => 'file', 'class'=>'uploadfrm'));?>
<fieldset class='registerf'>
    <legend class='registerf2'>Upload a Video</legend>
<?php
    echo 'Upload your video content here, there is no size limit however it is       <b>.mp4</b> file format only.';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo $this->Form->input('name', array('between'=>'<br />', 'class'=>'input'));
    echo $this->Form->input('eventname', array('between'=>'<br />'));
    echo $this->Form->input('description', array('between'=>'<br />', 'rows'=> '7', 'cols'=> '60'));
    echo  $this->Form->hidden('userid', array('id' => 'user_id','value' => $auth['id']));
    echo $this->Form->hidden('username', array('id' => 'username', 'value' => $auth['username']));
    echo $this->Form->input('file', array('type' => 'file'));
    echo "<br/>"
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
</fieldset>
```

```
     <?php

   class UploadsController extends AppController {
   public $name = 'Uploads';

      public $helpers = array('Js');



// Users memeber area, is User logged in…
 public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'RequestHandler',
    'Auth'=>array(
        'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'uploads', 'action'=>'browse'),
        'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login'),
        'authError'=>"Members Area Only, Please Login…",
        'authorize'=>array('Controller')
    )
  );


       public function isAuthorized($user) {
            // regular user can access the file uploads area
        if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'regular') {
            return true;
             }

             // Default deny
                return false;
            }





function index() {
        $this->set('users', $this->Upload->find('all'));

}




// Handling File Upload Function and updating uploads database


    public function add() {

        if(!empty($this->data)){

            $file = $this->request->data['Upload']['file'];
            if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
            $this->Upload->save($this->data); 
                if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],APP.'webroot/files/uploads'.DS.$this->Upload->id.'.mp4')) 
                {
                    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Uploads', 'action' => 'add'));
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('<p class="uploadflash">The upload has been saved</p>', true));


                    }   }else {

                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('<p class="uploadflash">The upload could not be saved. Please, try again.</p>', true));

                            }

                }
                }   

function browse () {
        // Find all in uploads database and paginates
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 5    ,
    'order' => array(
        'name' => 'asc'
    )
    );
    $data = $this->paginate('Upload');
    $this->set(compact('data'));


     }

function recentuploads () {
$uploads =  $this->Upload->find('all', 
    array('limit' =>7,
    'order' => 
        array('Upload.date_uploaded' => 'desc')));
    if(isset($this->params['requested'])) { 
         return $uploads; 
         } 
            $this->set('uploads', $uploads); 
}

function watch ($id = null){
$this->set('isAjax', $this->RequestHandler->isAjax());

    // Read Uploads Table to watch video
    $this->Upload->id = $id;      
    $this->set('uploads', $this->Upload->read());



    // Load Posts Model for comments related to video
            $this->loadModel('Post');
    $this->paginate = array(
                'conditions' => array(
                'uploadid' => $id),
                'limit' => 4
                );

    $data = $this->paginate('Post');
    $this->set(compact('data'));






// Load Likes Model and retrive number of likes and dislikes

    $this->loadModel('Like');

    $related_likes = $this->Like->find('count', array(
        'conditions' => array('uploadid' => $id)
    ));
    $this->set('likes', $related_likes);
    }




}
    ?>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add the following line in the function add

```
            $this->render();
```

everything works perfectly, I'm struggling for the life of me to work out why I have to render the view if surely all other views are rendered by default. 
But anyway got it working!
Hope this helps others :)

Answer (score 1):

This `add` function is in your UploadsController, correct?  And you want it to redirect to uploads/browse?

In your UploadsController, what is `$name` set to?

```
<?php
class UploadsController extends AppController {
   public $name = ?; // What is this variable set to?
}
```

By Cake's Inflector, when you specify controllers in a redirect, it should be lowercase:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'uploads', 'action' => 'browse'));
```

Or if the action you direct from and the action you want to direct to are in the same controller, you do not even need to specify the controller.  For example if you submit the form from UploadsController `add()` and you want to redirect to `browse()`:

```
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'browse'));
```

Try that and see if it helps.

Also note that you are calling $this->Upload->save($this->data) twice in your `add` function.

```
public function add() {

    if(!empty($this->data)){
        $file = $this->request->data['Upload']['file'];
        if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK && $this->Upload->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Upload->save($this->data);
            if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],APP.'webroot/files/uploads'.DS.$this->Upload->id.'.mp4')) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('<p class="uploadflash">The upload has been saved</p>', true));
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Uploads','action' => 'add'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('<p class="uploadflash">The upload could not be saved. Please, try again.</p>', true));
            }
        }
    } 

}
```

Specifically, here:

```
if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK && $this->Upload->save($this->data)) {
    $this->Upload->save($this->data);
    ...
```

When you call it in the `if` condition, it still saves the data to the database.  It is fine to remove the second one.

Comment: thanks for replying, the public name is set as Uploads, im trying to re-direct the form after submitting back to the uploadss/add form so that the flash can be set as a success and if they want they can upload another if they want but its not re-directing there or to any other page. 
Any suggestions at all??
Also thank you for the note on the save method, didn't notice that :)

Comment: Did you try `$this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));`?

Comment: yeah I've tried that already, could you think of anything that is causing it? should I post the whole controller? perhaps something else is causing it?

Comment: Just to make sure that the code is reaching the setFlash `$this->Session->setFlash(__('<p class="uploadflash">The upload has been saved</p>', true));`, have you tried debugging something?  For example, try adding the line `debug('test');` below the `setFlash` and tell me if it appears (you need to ensure debugging is on in your config file).  Also, I noticed your form is creating a Post as seen in: `<?php echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('action'=>'add'))`, but you are adding an "Upload"?  Maybe if you can give me a little more information, I can understand.

Comment: hi i tried the debugging but it still gave me a blank screen, also i posted the wrong form, I have revised the post, I still cant get to grips with whats wrong with it?? :/

Comment: ive also added the whole controller code incase theres an error you can spot?

Comment: i dont understand why i cant even redirect to any other view :S